# What is the filling of the stapler called in English? (picture attached)

Tags: word-request, image-identification

What is the **filling** of the **stapler** called in English? (you can see it in red circle in the attached picture).

I looked for this word in my native dictionary but I didn't find this word.

[image: A stapler with staples next to it]

Comment: What is the word in your native language? I'm curious.

Comment: Also know as a "clip of staples"

Comment: or, simply,, as "staples" - that's all that I have ever heard it called.

Answer (score 90):

I'd just call them "staples".

A set of staples joined together like this can be referred to as a "staple strip" or a "strip of staples", as in Eran's answer, but English speakers don't use this term very often.  Instead, most speakers simply refer to them as "staples" in normal speech.

That doesn't mean you *can't* talk about strips of staples.  You can talk about whether a stapler takes half strips or full strips, for example – the shorter ones take half strips.  But in common speech, it's usually most natural to just say "staples".

Comment: Yes. They are just "staples". A single used staple is, well, a "staple"!

Comment: For what it's worth, if I had to distinguish between a loose pile of staples and the thing that goes in a stapler, I'd probably say "staples, the way you put them in a stapler", as opposed to staple strip or anything more convenient like that.

Comment: I'd say "a thing of staples", relying on the fact that neither my audience nor I knows a good word for this!

Answer (score 18):

By the previous answers here, I found the following things:

In [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Staple_(fastener)#Paper_staples) they're called **paper staples**.
In [Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/staple?q=Staple%20%20) they're called simply **staples**.

Checking in google images shows that the boxes that contains them, call them  simply **staples**. ([See here](http://www.winc.com.au/main-catalogue-search?Ntt=staples&submit=&searchtrigger=globalsearch) for example)

**Staple strips**, [by googling](https://www.google.ch/search?biw=1366&bih=662&ei=ElI2WtnhLsnPkwWQq6v4Bg&q=%22Staple%20strips%22&oq=%22Staple%20strips%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3..35i39k1j0i7i30k1j0i30k1j0i8i30k1l3.2694.3876.0.4057.2.2.0.0.0.0.990.1116.0j1j6-1.2.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.2.1114....0.ORSyHYYfSM8) I found mainly as a term that can refer to paper staples, but not as name of product title for them but just generally referring to what it is called. I found also that "**staple strips**" as a product title name refers mainly to the staples that are not for papers, but for example for thicker things than paper or fences etc. For "paper staples strips" there are only [5 results](https://www.google.ch/search?biw=1366&bih=662&ei=jVM2WtOXFpK0sAfV0qa4Bg&q=%22paper%20Staple%20strips%22&oq=%22paper%20Staple%20strips%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i71k1l4.4221.4221.0.4413.1.1.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..1.0.0....0.yJxWbBZzmJ8) in google.

**Stapler needles** is a name that less common in English speaking countries (for example, by googling [I found 972 results](https://www.google.ch/search?biw=1366&bih=662&ei=y042WsHyCJKwsAeStLXIAg&q=%22stapler%20needles%22&oq=%22stapler%20needles%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...0.0.0.15253.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0....0...1c..64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.edC5_e-80bY), in which [46 results](https://www.google.ch/search?hl=en&as_q=&as_epq=Stapler%20needles&as_oq=&as_eq=&as_nlo=&as_nhi=&lr=&cr=countryGB&as_qdr=all&as_sitesearch=&as_occt=any&safe=images&as_filetype=&as_rights=) in the **UK** or [774 results](https://www.google.ch/search?hl=en&as_q=&as_epq=Stapler%20needles&as_oq=&as_eq=&as_nlo=&as_nhi=&lr=&cr=countryUS&as_qdr=all&as_sitesearch=&as_occt=any&safe=images&as_filetype=&as_rights=) in the **US** for "stapler needles"). I think it can tell everything about this usage.

[image]

Comment: There is no equivalent in your native language? Staplers are pretty common worldwide.

Comment: There is. But this is the story: my native dictionary that I use doesn't have this entry. But **in retrospect**, I did another reverse search (from English to my native language) and it shows me that what I called it in my language has a synonym that I didn't even know about that, and the entry was for this unknown word.

Comment: You know there is Google translator, it's not perfect but it has made some amazing advances in recent years. There is a glut of online dictionaries which also do translations. The Free Dictionary is one of the best. Once you have the name "stapler" it shouldn't be too hard to find "staple". If I thought you were looking for the strip of staples, that snailplane mentions, then I would have understood.

Comment: Instinctively, I would have called that section "a row", or "a column of staples", or "a packet of staples" for the container, and then I would check, not finding the definite answer is when I would have asked my question and ***showed*** my research.

Comment: "staples that are not for papers" : *collated* (which technically these are, but no one calls them that because no one sells loose staples that go in a machine). E.g., *Collated Nails, Screws & Staples* @ [Menards](https://www.menards.com/main/tools-hardware/fasteners-fastener-accessories/collated-nails-screws-staples/collated-staples/c-19719.htm)

Comment: I suspect they are only called "paper staples" when you are differentiating them from, say, wood staples or surgical staples.

Answer (score 7):

They are called staples.

[Definition from Merriam Webster dictionary here](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/staple)

Answer (score 5):

In our office we call them **staple sticks** or **staple cartridges**. But usually when you ask someone to give you those, you never mean to ask for singles, so even if you ask for just "staples", I'm sure you'll get a stick of them.

Comment: Upvote for "staple cartridges" - that's what I would call them (UK English speaker)

Answer (score 5):

I have always said "a row of staples" for the actual staples stuck together that you put into a stapler.

In the US, Swingline is the most known brand of stapler and here is [the usage for row of staples](https://www.google.com/search?ei=kac2Wo6yOoHmmAHw3oLgBQ&q=%22a%20row%20of%20staples%22%20swingline&oq=%22a%20row%20of%20staples%22%20swingline&gs_l=psy-ab.3..33i22i29i30k1l3.67670.70014.0.70371.14.14.0.0.0.0.197.1222.11j3.14.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.14.1219...0i22i30k1.0.NgtbjVXQZGY)

Answer (score 5):

In India, I have heard them called "stapler pins" most often. See, for example, listings on various shopping sites:

- [eBay India](https://www.ebay.in/sch/Stapler-and-Pins-/180642/i.html)
- [Stationery Hut](http://www.stationeryhut.in/kangaro-no-10-stapler-pins-20-boxes) (seems to be an Indian site)
- [Flipkart](https://www.flipkart.com/pens-stationery/office-supplies/staplers-pins-removers/pr?sid=dgv,tkw,lel) (Indian site)

Or various news articles:

- [FSSAI bans stapler pins in tea bags from January 2018](http://www.thehindubusinessline.com/news/fssai-bans-stapler-pins-in-tea-bags-from-january-2018/article9786729.ece) - *The Hindu Business Line*, July 24 2017.
- [‘Indecent obsessions’: A peek into life as a kleptomaniac, compulsive liar](http://www.hindustantimes.com/sex-and-relationships/indecent-obsessions-a-peek-into-life-as-a-kleptomaniac-compulsive-liar/story-cQQqxcRXYbz7iREFDkys7K.html) - *The Hindustan Times*, August 20, 2017 (emphasis mine):

  > Pencils, erasers, sharpeners, notepads, paper clips, even **stapler
  >   pins** – over the next nine years, Dandekar would stockpile stationery
  >   he never really wanted, and certainly did not need.
- [29 stapler pins removed from 10-month-old baby's oral cavity](http://www.dnaindia.com/india/report-29-stapler-pins-removed-from-10-month-old-baby-s-oral-cavity-2083718) - *Daily News & Analysis*, May 6, 2015.

Answer (score 4):

They're **staples**

Just wanted to point out that one of the world's largest office supplies companies based its name on these little things:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Staples_Inc.

From a marketing perspective, it has a dual meaning - a "staple" is typically a basic ingredient or material so widely used or consumed that it's considered essential to an everyday process. For example, rice and potatoes are staple foods in many parts of the world, cotton is a staple element of clothing.

By labelling themselves Staples, the office supplies company acquires the linguistic side effect of describing themselves as essential/being sellers of essential things

Answer (score 1):

a "bolt" of staples is what you call the attached line of staples.

Comment: Maybe you call it that, but I think not many others would.  I've never heard or seen it.

Answer (score 1):

As already answered, most people would just say they were "staples":

> I need to put some more staples in my stapler.

It may also be called "*a block of staples*" as they are stuck together.

Another alternative is that they may be referred to as a *cartridge*. Usually, a "cartridge" is a container with something inside, but the fact that the staples are sort of stuck together with a very fine adhesive makes them more than just "some staples". It is a single, collective object designed to be put into a stapler, and for that reason, I think "cartridge" is acceptible.

Answer (score 0):

They are called:

> **Stapler Needles**

or

> **Staple strips**.

Comment: Stapler needles are apparently came by analogy to other languages (such as: מהדק סיכות which is translated into "stapler needles"). Hanuka sameah!

Comment: @COX1 well, when I searched for "stapler needles" I got the relevant images :). And thanks!

Comment: I have never heard staple needles in my entire life, and it's been long.